# Nonetype error concatenating integers as strings Python

Tags: python, concatenation, nonetype

Hello stackoverflowbros

I came up with a fun problem to find all the years (in the recent future, before I day basically) for which all of the following are true:

```
1) the day is prime (eg the 5th or the 17th of the month)
2) the month is prime (eg May is the 5th month 5 is prime)
3) the year is prime (eg the year 2027 is prime)
4) the numbers concatenated in DDMMYYYY format is prime (eg 3022027 is prime)
```

My code works which is nice. I get the following answers:

```
3-02-2027    
13-02-2027
31-02-2027 ## February has 31 days now ok
31-05-2027
29-07-2027
```

But I also get told that the line `if isPrime(year) and isPrime(month) and isPrime(day) and isPrime(int(str(day) + datefix(month) + str(year))):`

Is `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'`

I have two questions: 1) what have I done wrong? 2) why do i only get answers in 2027 (kind of related, why do i get any answers at all if there's an error)

```
def isPrime(n) :

    # Corner cases
    if (n <= 1) :
        return False
    if (n <= 3) :
        return True

    # This is checked so that we can skip
    # middle five numbers in below loop
    if (n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0) :
        return False

    i = 5
    while(i * i <= n) :
        if (n % i == 0 or n % (i + 2) == 0) :
            return False
        i = i + 6

    return True

def datefix(y):

    if y <= 9:
        y = str(str(0) + str(y))
        return y

print(type(datefix(5)))


years = range(2019, 2054) ## 2053 is a good year to stop - and it's prime
days = range(2, 32)
months = range(2,13)

for year in years:
    for month in months:
        for day in days:
            if isPrime(year) and isPrime(month) and isPrime(day) and isPrime(int(str(day) + datefix(month) + str(year))):
                print(str(day) + '-' + datefix(month) + '-' + str(year))
```

Comment: In ```datefix``` when the if statement is not true, you get back a None.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well because `datefix` only returns `y` if `y <= 9`, then if it's not,
It returns `None`,  the default return type of a function in Python.
So in your example Month is bigger than 9.
The function `datefix` needs to handle that case.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually change your function `datefix` to a single line `datefix = '{:02d}'.format` to get left zero padded months. No need to account for cases greater/smaller 10.
Currently it returns `None` for arguments > 9, as mentioned in another answer.